# bitcoin mining on a laptop gpu, nvidia GT 120m?

Tags: miner-configuration, mining-profitability, gpu-mining, ubuntu

i have a laptop with a discreet GPU, no integrated ones.
its a Nvidia GT 120m in an ASUS laptop. 
i never use the laptop, so i decided to turn it into a bitcoin miner using bitminter.
at the moment it is just doing 4Mhps. while one of my desktops with a nvidia 8800GTS is doing 13Mhps. 
i believe the laptop gpu is suppose to be faster. 
anyone have any solutions to a problem like this.
oh and both systems use ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0):

Laptop gpus are no good for mining bitcoins. Not anymore, at least.

Comment: In future, some explanation is really needed to make an answer like this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your laptop GPU will be competing against miners who mine at GHps, people who have specialized hardware for mining. You're orders of magnitude slower than they are. Ultimately whether it is worth depends on how much time you have and the cost of electricity, but it will require a lot of patience.